# TypeError: Cannot read property 'hash' of null, webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js

I am trying to build my nextjs project but its failing every time. Project works without a single error in development but fails in build.
Tried deleting `node_modules` and reinstalling packages but no luck.

After long searching I finally found [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69341735/typeerror-cannot-read-property-hash-of-null) of this, but it has been removed by its author.

Build log

```
> next build

info  - Loaded env from /home/user/Documents/projects/webdev/myproject/.env.local
info  - Using webpack 5. Reason: Enabled by default https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5
info  - Checking validity of types
info  - Creating an optimized production build .../home/user/Documents/projects/webdev/myproject/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:59190
                                                                processContextHashSnapshot(path, tsh.hash);
                                                                                                     ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'hash' of null
    at callback (/home/user/Documents/projects/webdev/myproject/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:59190:46)
    at /home/user/Documents/projects/webdev/myproject/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:57683:39
    at /home/user/Documents/projects/webdev/myproject/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:135587:5
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/home/user/Documents/projects/webdev/myproject/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:33832:10), <anonymous>:4:1)
    at AsyncQueue._handleResult (/home/user/Documents/projects/webdev/myproject/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:135557:21)
    at /home/user/Documents/projects/webdev/myproject/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:135540:11
    at /home/user/Documents/projects/webdev/myproject/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:59794:14
    at /home/user/Documents/projects/webdev/myproject/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:59452:6
    at done (/home/user/Documents/projects/webdev/myproject/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/neo-async/async.js:1:10308)
    at /home/user/Documents/projects/webdev/myproject/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:59736:9
    at /home/user/Documents/projects/webdev/myproject/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:135587:5
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/home/user/Documents/projects/webdev/myproject/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:33832:10), <anonymous>:4:1)
    at AsyncQueue._handleResult (/home/user/Documents/projects/webdev/myproject/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:135557:21)
    at /home/user/Documents/projects/webdev/myproject/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:135540:11
    at /home/user/Documents/projects/webdev/myproject/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:59794:14
    at /home/user/Documents/projects/webdev/myproject/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:59452:6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it by clearing the vercel build cache by using the `--force` flag during deployment.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting `.next/` dir solved my problem.